# How to install nvidia geforce gtx1050 driver in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, server, software-installation, virtualbox, nvidia-geforce

I tried all the possible ways to install nvidia geforce gtx 1050 driver in my ubuntu.but failed all the time. what to do now ?

Comment: note: in virtualbox

Comment: @Md.Jaish virtualbox does not use actual hardware so no you do not install a video card driver.